# How to get data definition of all tables from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2012 and I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 version 10. I can get list of all tables from schema using:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.tables;
```

And I can get all details about a particular table say table1 using:

```
sp_help table1;
```

Is there a way I can get all details (data definition) for all the tables in the schema in a xls? Something like by combining above two queries like (this is not valid SQL):

```
sp_help in (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables)
```

Comment: Perhaps use `information_schema.columns` instead.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio allows you to export table definitions as a SQL file. You can open that in Excel if you like but it won't look very good!

Answer (score 1):

Taken basically straight from the stored proc with a little modification. Note this only shows one portion of the SP. You may have to go into the SP yourself to grab more if needed. All you need to do is right-click and choose modify.

```
--SP_HELP Table1
DECLARE @dbname SYSNAME
    ,@no VARCHAR(35), @yes VARCHAR(35), @none VARCHAR(35)
SELECT @no = 'no', @yes = 'yes', @none = 'none'

DECLARE @precscaletypes NVARCHAR(150)
SELECT @precscaletypes = N'TINYINT,SMALLINT,DECIMAL,INT,BIGINT,REAL,MONEY,FLOAT,NUMERIC,SMALLMONEY,DATE,TIME,DATETIME2,DATETIMEOFFSET,'




SELECT 
        'Column_name'           = name,
        'Type'                  = TYPE_NAME(user_type_id),
        'Computed'              = CASE WHEN ColumnProperty(object_id, name, 'IsComputed') = 0 THEN @no ELSE @yes END,
        'Length'                    = CONVERT(INT, max_length),
        'Prec'                  = CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX(TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) + ',', @precscaletypes) > 0
                                    THEN CONVERT(CHAR(5),ColumnProperty(object_id, name, 'precision'))
                                    ELSE '     ' END,
        'Scale'                 = CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX(TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) + ',', @precscaletypes) > 0
                                    THEN CONVERT(CHAR(5),OdbcScale(system_type_id,scale))
                                    ELSE '     ' END,
        'Nullable'              = CASE WHEN  IS_NULLABLE = 0 THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END,
        'TrimTrailingBlanks'    = CASE ColumnProperty(OBJECT_ID, name, 'UsesAnsiTrim')
                                    WHEN 1 THEN @no
                                    WHEN 0 THEN @yes
                                    ELSE '(n/a)' END,
        'FixedLenNullInSource'  = CASE 
                    WHEN TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) NOT IN  ('VARBINARY','VARCHAR','BINARY','CHAR')
                        THEN '(n/a)'
                    WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 0 THEN @no ELSE @yes 
                    END,
        'Collation'     = collation_name
    FROM sys.all_columns WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I got a sql from net and it does pull all the details about each table in the schema. But as it is dynamic SQL I am not able to export it's result from SQL Server management Studio 2012. The SQL is: 


Declare Asql Nvarchar(MAX)
Set Asql = N''

Select Asql = Asql + N'
EXEC sp_help ''['+TABLE_SCHEMA+N'].['+TABLE_NAME+N']'';'
 From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 
Print N'Executing:
'+Asql+'
'
EXEC(Asql)


Sorry, I am unable to format this reply properly using code tags, line break etc. Couldn't add <code> tag so @ was giving error. I replaced @ with A.